# ЧПУ для бесконечного дерева

Tags: .htaccess, дерево, чпу

Есть таблица в базе с полями id и parent_id
Вложенность соответственно может быть бесконечная.

Не понимаю как мне сделать ЧПУ через htaccess на сайте вида site.ru/cat1/cat2/cat3/.../catN и так же как выводить на php

Подскажите люди грамотные.